# How to make multiple object in one request put or delete? Django Rest

Tags: python, django

It allow me to pass in json format data to post for creating record after i make def create so that json format like [{data:data,data:data}] can post in. How should i do so that i can also make put request with multiple object in one request or using post method to update?

Below is views.py.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import ListForm

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import ListFormSerializer
from rest_framework import filters
import django_filters.rest_framework

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, viewsets

class ListFormViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = ListForm.objects.all().order_by('group')
    serializer_class = ListFormSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filterset_fields = ['group','key_description'] 
    search_fields = ['group']

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data,list))
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()) 
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset) 
        if page is not None: 
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)

            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

            serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

        # return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import action

import json
from .models import Post
from .serializers import PostSerializer

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = Post.objects.none()
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def update_this(self, request):

        try:
            data = json.loads(request.data)
        except:
            try:
                data = dict(request.data)
            except:
                data = request.data

        # You can do everything you want here with data

        return Response({'code': 0, 'desc': 'OK', 'more_data': {}})
```

Comment: Hi could you give me an example on the code how to write create or save under the #you can do everything you want here with data?

Comment: im also get NameError: name 'action' is not defined

Comment: Sorry @Desmondmeng I forgot to "action" import with `from rest_framework.decorators import action`, is updated now. And you can do something like:  `Post.objects.filter(some_field_id=data['some_field_id]).update(some_text = data['some_text']...) or Post.objects.create(my_field_1 = data['my_field_1')...)`, everything is posible there.